# How to use registers in kprobe?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, trace, kprobe

From [kprobe document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/kprobetrace.txt):

```
echo 'p:myprobe do_sys_open dfd=%ax filename=%dx flags=%cx mode=+4($stack)' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events
```

Per my understanding, on `X86_64` platform, the arguments should be passed into registers (please refer [X86_64 syscalls](https://w3challs.com/syscalls/?arch=x86_64)). So I think adding probe should like this:

```
echo 'p:myprobe do_sys_open dfd=%rdi filename=%rsi flags=%rdx mode=%rcx' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events
```

But execute the above statement, `bash` complains:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

So my questions is: how to use registers in `kprobe`? Which registers are valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing with `kprobe` maintainer, I get the answer:

`ftrace-kprobe` interface does not accept bitwidth prefix like '`rax`' instead it accepts '`ax`'. The bitwidth is automatically chosen by architecture. So please remove '`r`' from all arguments. If you'd like to access `eax` or `ax`, you can use typecast, like as `%ax:u32`.